# Problem with ForbiddenHttpException in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I try to execute this code in controller

```
throw new ForbiddenHttpException();
```

I excpeted to see 403 error, but I see following error:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException: You are not allowed to perform this action. in C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:158
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php(140): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(77): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(627): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(276): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(155): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(108): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\university\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException))
#10 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException))
#11 {main}
```

Comment: your question is not clear   .you have missed  the code  .. . you should add the link  you are using and the related  coontroller ..  behaviors function code  (in top of controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add a rule for error action in access rules 
you can use this code in behaviors:

```
  [
       'actions' => ['error'],
       'allow' => true,
       'roles' => ["?","@"],
  ],
```

or in access rules use `only` for actions you need permission

Comment: @MiladKazemi My pleasure!